# Positive continuous random variable. Determining he c.d.f and p.d.f

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a positive continuous random variable with density f$_x$(x)=1/x$^4$.

Comment: "I know natural logs can only take on positive values of X..."—the natural logarithm is only *defined* for positive values. It can *take on* all values in $(-\infty,\infty)$ and in fact for $0<x<1$, $\log(x)<0$. I'm sure you know this but feel it should be addressed.

Comment: Correct.What I meant-just poorly worded on my side.

Comment: Another issue is that the support for $X$ is not provided. That is, we must have $\int f_X(x) dx=1$ over where $f_X(x)$ is defined but at most you have provided that $X$ is positive, so $0<x<\infty$, but then the normalization doesn't hold over this entire domain as $\int_0^\infty x^{-4} dx$ diverges. If instead the PDF is defined over $(1,\infty)$ then the integral is finite but not normalized, $\int_1^\infty x^{-4} dx=1/3$. So what is the support exactly?

Comment: That I would need a constant of 3 so that it actually totals to an area of 1, correct?

Comment: Yes, if you define $f_X(x)=3x^{-4}$ on $[1,\infty)$ then it is a valid PDF. But it is unclear if you had another domain in mind or not. This is just one particular domain.

Comment: sorry I'm still new with all this so my c.d.f would be 3$x^-4$ and this would be showing me which values are most likely?

Comment: or should I be interacting ln(x)? I'm a little confused why I am provide two different equations in this case.

Comment: I have added an answer to avoid an extended comment discussion. I hope it will clear up the confusion but you may certainly comment on it for further clarification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87220/discussion-between-lil-and-lovetoonap29).

Comment: Why edit the question to remove nearly all of its content after already getting two answers? Best to delete it if you don’t want it up, imo.

Answer (score 0):

My comments about the PDF just have to do with the fact that the problem is ill-posed as written in the sense that $f_X(x)=x^{-4}$ is not a valid PDF on $(0,\infty)$ or $(1,\infty)$, for instance, and so the problem cannot continue from here.

**Change of variables:**
Let's work with $f_X(x)=3x^{-4}$ on $[1,\infty)$. Then this is a valid PDF ($f\geq 0$ and $\int f=1$). The CDF is then $\int_1^x 3u^{-4}du=1-x^{-3}$ for $x>1$.

I will sketch out the change of variables technique for you.

Let $Y=\log(X)$. To find $f_Y(y)$, let $h$ be any bounded measurable function on $\mathbb{R}$, then we first consider the integral,
$$\mathbb{E}(h(Y))=\int h(y)f_Y(y) dy=\int_1^\infty h(\log(x)) f_X(x) dx=\mathbb{E}(h(\log(X)),$$
using the [law of unconscious statisticians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). Now use the subtitution $y=\log x$, which implies $x=e^y$, and since $1<x<\infty$, we have $0<y<\infty$ and finally $e^y dy =dx$. Proceeding, with the substitution,
$$\int_1^\infty h(\log(x)) f_X(x) dx=\int_0^\infty h(y) f_X(e^y) e^y dy$$
$$=\int_0^\infty h(y) 3e^{-3y}dy$$
but since this holds for all bounded measurable functions $h$ we must have by identification that $f_Y(y)=3e^{-3y}$. One can check that this is a valid PDF on $(0,\infty)$ and further recognize it as the PDF of an exponential random variable with rate parameter $\lambda=3$ (and so mean $1/3$, etc).

Comment for further clarifications or questions that would not warrant a new post. If this change of variable technique is unfamiliar, peruse the link CruZ provided or find a calculus book and look up "change of variable" or "substitution" or "change of variable technique" or "transformations of random variables" in a probability textbook.

**EDIT**
Here we derive the CDF of $Y$ first then differentiate to obtain the PDF of $Y$. 
We still use $f_X(x)=3x^{-4}$ on $(1,\infty)$. 
First, since, $1<X<\infty$ and $Y=\log X$, we have
$$Y\leq y \iff \log X \leq y \iff X\leq e^{y}.$$
So that upon taking probabilities, 
$$\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X\leq e^{y}),$$
or in terms of CDFs,
$$F_Y(y)=F_X(e^{y})$$
and now all you have to do is plug in $x=e^{y}$ into $F_X(x)=1-x^{-3}$ and this gives you $F_Y(y)$. Finally, differentiate with respect to $y$ to get $f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y)=3e^{-3y}$. These last steps I have purposely left out detail because it's algebra and calculus at this point and not probability proper. Go through the steps yourself to verify it works and practice what will eventually become routine computations. Beware that the CDF technique requires that the function $Y=g(X)$ is invertible and thus cannot be applied blindly (here $y=g(x)=\log x$ and has inverse $g^{-1}(y)=e^y$).

Comment: Yes, if we take the PDF $f_X(x)=x^{-2}$ on $(1,\infty)$ then it has the CDF $F_X(x)=1-x^{-1}$ which is obtained by integration, correct. If you want the PDF and CDF of $Y=\log(X)$ you need to perform the change of variable technique as I demonstrated. Here $Y$ is a *new* random variable that is a *function of* $X$, so computing the PDF amounts to a change of variables. To get the CDF of $Y$ one then integrates the PDF. You could also try to find the CDF of  $Y$ first and then differentiate to obtain the PDF of $Y$ but that is not always easy.

Comment: would obtaining the CDF of Y be difficult in this Case you believe?

Comment: I’ll edit the answer to include it at the bottom—my goto is change of variable since it is typically more applicable but since you haven’t learned it yet it’s obviously not immediately helpful (it will be in the future though!)

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate all your help!

Comment: @Lil Your welcome! If you feel satisfied, you may consider accepting it by clicking the green check under the voting arrows. Otherwise, comment for more clarification.

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:**

You can find the PDF for Y using transformation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

When you have the PDF for Y you can integrate to find the CDF.